# Joining data from different data contexts

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

In my project, I'm using two different data contexts to pass the data to the view from the list.

For that, I wrote the code as this.

```
private zSqlLink dbs = new zSqlLink();
private zSqlData db = new zSqlData();
// GET: Selfcare

public ActionResult PendingSelfTasks() {
  IEnumerable < SelfCareTasks > pendingTasks = new List < SelfCareTasks > ();

  var list = (from l in dbs.SelfCareTasks 
              where l.Is_Service_Accepted == false && l.Status == true 
              select new {
              l.Id, 
              l.Service_Id, 
              l.Customer_Id, 
              l.Service_End_Date, 
              l.Service_Price
              }
              ).ToList();

  pendingTasks = (from d in list 
                  join c in db.Customer on d.Customer_Id equals c.Id 
                  join ser in db.Services on d.Service_Id equals ser.Id 
                  select new SelfCareTasks 
                  {
                  Id = d.Id,
                  CustomerName = c.Sur_Name + " " + c.Name,
                  ServiceName = ser.Service_NameEng,
                  ServicePrice = d.Service_Price,
                  EndDate = d.Service_End_Date.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")
                  }).ToList();

  return View(pendingTasks);
}
```

First I created a List and add the required main data from `Context 1`.

And then Joined that Data with the other context data tables to get the values and pass to the view.

When I debug the code, it returns these errors

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out

Comment: Try extending the `CommandTimeout` on both of your contexts: `dbs.Database.CommandTimeout = 300;` . Please note that the command timeout value is in seconds.

Comment: @RahulSharma I did that, but still returns the same.

Comment: Are you sure the timeout occurs on the 2nd query?  also check if there are indexes on all fields used in the joins. and can you give an approximate number of rows in list?

Answer (score 0):

Try to optimize your query. CommandTimeout exception usually occurs when loading large amount of data using joins.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).